# In Humankind, can units heal on vassal territory?

Tags: humankind

Damaged units in the game Humankind, can they heal on a vassal state of yours?

Answer (score 1):

I've confirmed units can heal on **your** vassal.

Would be nice to know/confirm if you are a vassal if you can heal on your "Vassal-liege". Seems like it's a "friendly territory" thing. This is not clear in the game encyclopedia, as far as I can tell.